# SQL on UPDATE save old data into another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: `players` and `history_of_players`.

I want to make some kind of history for the players, so if someone updates `'club'` in players table, I want the old data (old club) to be saved into `'history_of_players'` with `'player_ID'`, `'old_club'` and `'year'`(actual year).

Comment: I think a simpler approach would be to have the history record entered after the initial insert and after any update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used MySQL for a while but this should be what you are looking for (if there is always just one row in the player table for each player_ID):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER historise BEFORE UPDATE ON players
  FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       INSERT INTO history_of_players (player_ID, old_club, year)
       SELECT player_ID, old_club, year FROM players
       WHERE player_ID = OLD.player_ID;
     END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Actually I thought it's good but it's alerting me with an error that there is no player_ID in OLD :D DO you know how can I fix that? :)

Comment: The trigger should only fire on UPDATE and not on INSERT, so `OLD.player_ID` should always contain a valid ID. If player_ID doesn't change, you could simply exchange `OLD` with `NEW` (using the inserted player_ID instead of the previously stored one).

Comment: I solved it already, but thanks. I hope it's good... I've just put there WHERE player_ID = player_ID before it updates and it's working for now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to create a trigger on the `players` table. For example:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER playersHistoryTrigger
AFTER UPDATE ON players
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO playersHistory
    VALUES (NEW.ID, NEW.Name, ...);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a trigger.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER playerup BEFORE UPDATE ON players
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO history_of_players (player_ID, old_club, date)
        VALUES (NEW.player_ID, OLD.club, CURDATE());
    END;//
```